# Trouble using nested for loops in algorithm

Tags: algorithmic

I am trying to write an algorithm which contains nested for loops as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\title{Algorithm example}

\author{\LaTeX{}}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Gibbs sampling Algorithm}

Algorithms can be included using the commands as shown in algorithm \ref{alg:gibbs}.

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Collapsed Gibbs sampling algorithm for inference}\label{alg:gibbs}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Choose initial $z$ and $\xi$.
\For{$T$ iterations}
  \For{$D$ Subjects}
    \For{$N_d$ time segments}
      \State do something
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

... and I get following errors:

```
Undefined control sequence
Package algorithmicx: Some blocks are not closed!!!
```

I am using IEEE's online template and also checked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247222/algorithm-nested-for-loops-generate-a-blank-line) question about nested for loops with algorithm, with no luck.

---

## EDIT 1:

Changed `\Endfor` to `\EndFor`. The errors disappeared but, gives me same output.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @dexteritas, Agreed! Made requisite changes.

Comment: Do you want another output or is the Question answered?

Comment: Although I am not seeing errors anymore, I still get the same output i.e. I don't see an `end for` line to terminate the for loop.

Comment: Than you have to remove the `noend` at `\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}`.

Comment: Removing `[noend]` did it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: [`algpseudocode` without end block text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51295/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you are compiling your document in "batch mode", which does not stop at errors but tries to continue, skipping problems.

In your case, the complete error message says:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.16 \Endfor
```

So the problem is that the command `\Endfor` is not recognized, but tex tries to continue nevertheless, and later produces another arror about blocks not being closed.

The problem is solved by writing `\EndFor` (which is the correct spelling of this command) instead of `\Endfor`.

If you want to see the "end for" in the output, remove the `noend` option in the package ;-)

Comment: I made that change and I no longer see the errors. However, I am still getting same output.

Comment: @kedarps But the output is correct, isn't? What did you expect?

Comment: @kedarps Oh, I saw your other comment under the question. Updated answer